# Box turn effect

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I want to implement a box turn effect at mouseover as in the following site:

http://pepsi.com/
(See the boxes below the animation)

It is made using Flash, but I want to develop it using something else.
Is that be possible?

Comment: Answer: Yes - But please spare everyone's eyes and don't implement it. There's enough flashing, spinning, turning, and blinking going on in the world without more of it.

Comment: I agree with Peter. Don't do it without a good reason, it's like another blink tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in something like jQuery.  There are plenty of examples where you can turn a div and all you need to do is when the div is at it's narrowest then you substitute the graphic for another one and continue turning.

Though I have to agree with @Peter, Please don't!

http://lab.smashup.it/flip/